# Correct draggable element's pixel position to start from a arbitrary corner

Tags: javascript, css-position, draggable, mousemove, pointer-events

The element containing a `draggable` or `moveable` handle can only start from the `top` `left` position, I have no idea how to adjust, calculate or correct the pixel values to make the draggable handle element start from say the bottom left like a normal graph would.

The position of the `handle` is used to generate a range restricted value like a percentage value between `0-100` for both the `x` and `y` axis regardless of the element's pixel size.

It's a range-input or position picker of sorts intended for use in a color picker widget.
The color gradients change depending on the widget's relative position to the left, top or right of something, hence the picker or handle should adjust the starting point of it's range accordingly.

I'm using `onpointermove` to get the `x` and `y` positions of the `div.handle` and 
adjust for the relative `width`, `height`, `left` and `top`,  offsets of the parent element.

What I cannot figure out for the life of me is the math and code needed to allow the range input to track the position from an arbitrary corner, preferably `bottom` `left`.

Sorry for using a custom library but this example is mostly vanilla, at least the calculations which matter are.

```js
const {dom, component, each, on, once, isNum, $, run} = rilti

// keep a number between a minimum and maximum ammount
const clamp = (n, min, max) => Math.min(Math.max(n, min), max)

// define element behavior
component('range-input', {
  // set up everything before element touches DOM
  create (range /* Proxy<Function => Element> */) {
    // setup zero values in state (observer-like abstraction tracking changes)
    range.state({value: 0, valueX: 0, valueY: 0})

    // local vars for easier logic
    let Value, ValueY

    // create element <div class="handle"> and append to <range-input>
    // also add property to range and get it as a const
    const handle = range.handle = dom.div.handle({$: range})

    // set the range limits at 0-100% by default for X and Y axis
    if (range.limit == null) range.limitX = range.limit = 100
    if (range.limit !== range.limitX) range.limitX = range.limit
    if (range.limitY == null) range.limitY = range.limit

    // set the X position by percentage/range number,
    // move the handle accordingly and change state
    range.setX = (value = range.value || 0, skipChecks) => {
      if (!skipChecks && value === Value) return
      if (value > range.limitX || value < 0) throw new Error('value out of range')
      
      // if the element is not in the dom
      // then wait for it to mount first
      if (!range.mounted) {
        range.once.mount(e => range.setX(value))
        return
      }

      // allow float values or round it to ints by default
      if (!range.decimals) value = Math.round(value)

      const hWidth = handle.offsetWidth
      // get pixel range
      const Min = hWidth / 2
      const Max = range.offsetWidth - Min
      // calculate pixel postion from range value
      const hLeft = (value / range.limitX) * (Max - Min)
      handle.style.left = hLeft + 'px'
      // update all the states
      Value = range.state.value = range.state.valueX = value
    }
    
    // same as setX but for Y axis
    range.setY = (value = range.valueY || 0, skipChecks) => {
      if (!skipChecks && value === Value) return
      if (value > range.limitY || value < 0) throw new Error('value out of range')
      if (!range.mounted) {
        range.once.mount(e => range.setY(value))
        return
      }
      const hHeight = handle.offsetHeight
      const Min = hHeight / 2
      const Max = range.offsetHeight - Min
      const hTop = (value / range.limitY) * (Max - Min)
      handle.style.top = hTop + 'px'

      if (!range.decimals) value = Math.round(value)
      ValueY = range.state.valueY = value
    }

    // get the raw Element/Node and define (s/g)etters
    Object.defineProperties(range() /* -> <range-input> */, {
      value: {get: () => Value, set: range.setX},
      valueX: {get: () => Value, set: range.setX},
      valueY: {get: () => ValueY, set: range.setY}
    })

    let rWidth // range.offsetWidth
    let rHeight // range.offsetHeight
    let rRect // cache of range.getBoundingClientRect()
    // called when user moves the handle
    const move = (x = 0, y = 0) => {
      // check the the axis is not locked
      // for when you want to use range-input as a slider
      if (!range.lockX) {
        // adjust for relative position
        if (x < rRect.left) x = rRect.left
        else if (x > rRect.left + rWidth) x = rRect.left + rWidth
        x -= rRect.left

        const hWidth = handle.offsetWidth
        
        // get pixel range
        const min = hWidth / 2
        const max = rWidth - min

        // keep it inside the block
        const hLeft = clamp(x, min, max) - min
        handle.style.left = hLeft + 'px'

        // pixel position -> percentage/value
        let value = (hLeft * range.limitX) / (max - min)
        
        // round value to an int by default
        if (!range.decimals) value = Math.round(value)
        
        // set it if it's not the same as the old value
        if (value !== Value) {
          Value = range.state.value = range.state.valueX = value
        }
      }

      // now do below as above for Y axis
      if (!range.lockY) { // when it's not locked
        if (y < rRect.top) y = rRect.top
        else if (y > rRect.top + rWidth) y = rRect.top + rHeight
        y -= rRect.top

        const hHeight = handle.offsetHeight
        const min = hHeight / 2
        const max = range.offsetHeight - min

        const hTop = clamp(y, min, max) - min
        handle.style.top = hTop + 'px'
        let value = (hTop * range.limitY) / (max - min)
        if (!range.decimals) value = Math.round(value)
        if (value !== ValueY) {
          ValueY = range.state.valueY = value
        }
      }

      // .dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('input'))
      range.emit('input')
      // call an update function if it's present as a prop
      if (range.update) range.update(range, handle)
    }

    // track and manage starting, stopping and moving events
    // for .pointer(up/down/move) event types respectively.
    const events = range.state.events = {
      move: on.pointermove(document, e => move(e.x, e.y)).off(),

      stop: on.pointerup(document, () => {
        events.move.off()
        events.start.on()
      }).off(),

      start: once.pointerdown([range, handle], () => {
        [rWidth, rHeight] = [range.offsetWidth, range.offsetHeight]
        rRect = range.getBoundingClientRect()
        events.move.on()
        events.stop.on()
      }).off()
    }
    //    ^-- all the events are off at the start
    //        they get turned on when the element mounts
  },
  
  // when Element enters DOM set the positions
  mount (range) {
    if (!range.lockY) range.handle.style.top = 0
    range.setX()
    range.setY()
    // start listening for user interactions
    range.state.events.start.on()
  },
  
  // start listening again on DOM re-entry
  remount (range) {
    range.state.events.start.on()
  },
  
  // stop listening when removed from DOM
  unmount ({state: {events}}) { each(events, e => e.off()) },
  
  // track custom attribute to set some props conveniently
  attr: {
    opts (range, val) {
      run(() => // wait for DOMContentLoaded first
        val.split(';')
          .filter(v => v != null && v.length)
          .map(pair => pair.trim().split(':').map(part => part.trim()))
          .forEach(([prop, value]) => {
            if (value.toLowerCase() === 'true') value = true
            else if (value.toLowerCase() === 'false') value = false
            else {
              const temp = Number(value)
              if (isNum(temp)) value = temp
            }
            if (prop === 'x' || prop === 'v') {
              range.setX(value, true)
            } else if (prop === 'y') {
              range.setY(value, true)
            } else {
              range[prop] = value
            }
          })
        )
    }
  }
})

// show the values of the range-input
$('span.stats').append($('range-input').state`
  X: ${'valueX'}%, Y: ${'valueY'}%
`)

// add a title
dom.h4('<range-input>: custom element').prependTo('body')
```

```css
range-input {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin: 1em auto;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

range-input > div.handle {
  position: absolute;
  background: #ccc;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  cursor: grab;
  user-drag: none;
  user-select: none;
  touch-action: none;
}



.details {
  width: 225px;
  text-align: left;
  margin: 3em auto;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  text-align: center;
  color: hsl(0,0%,40%);
}

h4 {
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<range-input opts="x: 35; y: 80;"></range-input>

<span class="stats"></span>

<section class="details">
  <p>
    <b>Please Help:</b><br>
    I can't figure out how to code it so that
    the range-input could start at an arbitrary corner
    instead of just top left.
    I'd like it to start counting from bottom left instead.
  </p>

<pre style="text-align: left;"><code>
// the handle should be able to start at
left: 0;
bottom: 0;
// with X/Y being zero;
// not sure how to achieve this.
</code></pre>

</section>

<script src="https://rawgit.com/SaulDoesCode/rilti.js/experimental/dist/rilti.js"></script>
```

Same example on
[Codepen](https://codepen.io/SaulDoesCode/pen/yqYXra?editors=0010)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to describe your issue is that your y-axis goes from 100 (technically, limitY) to 0 when it ought to go from 0 to 100. Therefore, we can slightly change your code to reverse this axis by fully calculating the y percentage, and then subracting it from 100. (ie, 100 - 80 = 20 or 100 - 35 - 65.) This will change the high values into low values and vice versa. Then, if we want to convert from percentage to pixel, we simply subtract it from 100 again to get our original flipped percentage (that you've already done all of the work for.)

The two lines changed are:

```
const hTop = (value / range.limitY) * (Max - Min)
```

becomes

```
const hTop = (1 - value / range.limitY) * (Max - Min)
// 1 - value / range.limitY is a shortening of (range.limitY - value) / range.limitY
```

and

```
let value = (hTop * range.limitY) / (max - min)
```

becomes

```
let value = range.limitY * (1 - hTop / (max - min))
// this is also a shortening, you could have written it,
// value = range.limitY - (hTop * range.limitY) / (max - min)
```

Here's the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NBxjVz?editors=0010).

Likewise, if you want to flip the x axis, you can use similar logic on that part of the code. You can flip various combinations of the two axes to start at various corners.

A harder version of the same problem (a good exercise for practice) is how to properly convert from your pixel, not just to a percentage, but also to any range `a` to `b`, with `b` possibly being smaller than `a`.

Comment: oh magic! Wonderful many thanks. Your answer makes sense, I knew it was a simple fix just couldn't figure it out.